# Plotting using table function

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to generate a plot in mathematica using the Table function. Below is an example of what I'm trying to produce:

```
f[x_, y_, z_]:= (x + y + z)^2
Table[f[1, 2, x=z], {z, 0, 10, 2}]= {9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169}
```

Now I want to plot the output from `Table[f[1, 2, z], {z, 0, 10, 2}]` against the same range of z values inputed into the function (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10). I have tried all sorts but really can't get it to work. It should be pretty basic but I haven't used mathematica in a while-appreciate your help with this

Thanks

Comment: ListPlot[{9, 25, 49, 81, 121, 169}, DataRange -> {0, 10}]

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel-I completely forgot about `ListPlot`. That `DataRange` option is pretty handy for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use the `ListLinePlot` with `{{x,y},...}` input. For this you need to transpose the `x,y` data that you have.

I changed your `x=z` in the code to just `z`. I did not see a reason to write `x=z` there.

```
ClearAll[x, y, z];
f[x_, y_, z_] := (x + y + z)^2
range = Range[0, 10, 2]
data = Table[f[1, 2, z], {z, range}]
mat = Transpose[{range, data}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is your `{x,y}` data. Now plot it using

```
ListLinePlot[mat, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your solution Nasser